# How to create shorten text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML like :

```
<div class="box">
   <a href="#">Stackoverflow is very useful site and I love it</a>
</div>
```

and CSS like :

```
.box {
    width:230px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    background:#eee;
}

.box a {
    color:#000;
}
```

I want create shorten text of link. If it itself overflow the `box` class, then take it by "...". How can I do that with css or jquery?

Check jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B9fjg/)

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417544/truncate-paragraph-first-100-character-and-hide-rest-content-of-paragraph-to-sho

Comment: There's no need to put it in jquery , unless if you have a button that say make it shorten

Comment: Thanks all support me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add following styles to `.box`:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/qLzK7/

Answer (score 3):

You need to set text-overflow: ellipsis for that purpose [see this link for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Answer (score 3):

```
.box a 
{
    color:#000;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
.box{
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 .box{
width:230px; 
height:50px;
line-height:50px
;background:#eee; 
overflow:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.box a{color:#000}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9yatw/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 37;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    $('.box').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).find("a").html();
        if(content.length > showChar) {
         var a = content.substr(0, showChar);
         var b = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);
         var html = a + ' ' + ellipsestext;
            $(this).find("a").html(html);
        }

    });
});
```