# Need to shorten the length of the text output by a function

Tags: php

I am a newbie. Figured out how to show property descriptions on property preview pages, but I want to only show a portion of the description, to cut it off and add to be continued dots ...

Few questions:

1. Is this the best way to display a property description?
2. How do you shorten the amount of text displayed?
3. How do you add the dots at the end?

This successfully displays the property description, however, I don't know where to start in shortening it and adding dots.

Comment: 1) It depends on how you design your website, we can't tell it is the best or not. 2) use `substr($yourstring, $star_position, $end_position)` function. 3) Simple concatenation is enough

Comment: @catcon Thank you. This worked echo substr (get_the_content(), 0, 100). ("...");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP/jQuery Shorten string and show more on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637641/php-jquery-shorten-string-and-show-more-on-click)