# Get first paragraph text from JSON list response object properties

Tags: javascript, json

I want to filter the first paragraph from the `course_description` object properties. I need only the first paragraph as highlighted in the screenshot. (a big rectangle)

```
var description = apiData[i].course_description;
console.log(description);
reshtm += '<div class="col-md-6">\
                <a href="coursesdetails" class="well">\
                    <h1>'+apiData[i].course_name+'</h1>\
                    <p>'+apiData[i].course_description+'</p>\
                </a>\
            </div>';
```

[image]

Screenshot of response
[image]

Comment: It would help if you could give the entire api response or the structure.

Comment: I just want to filter the text inside the `apiData[i].course_description;` why all response is necessary? Please help.

Comment: What is the data type of `apiData[i].course_description`?

Comment: Its a string. the screenshot I post is of console.log. I added screenshot aswelll. Thanks.

Comment: There is no JSON in this question.

Comment: @axiac I have added few minutes back. Please check. I have added the screenshot of json response for that particular object properties.

Comment: The question is still not about JSON. What you ask is a simple string processing that can be done in several ways using the [methods of `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your string format (SS) , you can do something like below

```
var description = apiData[i].course_description.split("\r")[0]; // get first para
console.log(description);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var elem  = document.createElement('DIV');
elem.innerHTML = apiData[i].course_description;
var result = elem.firstChild;
console.log(result);
```

PS: You might get the escaped characters in the result which you can later trim it off.

Comment: Your answer helps but still it returns the text as [Object Text] not sure what next to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use truncate function like [here](http://The%20answer%20is%20here%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417544/truncate-paragraph-first-100-character-and-hide-rest-content-of-paragraph-to-sho)